# Why is the variable dowloadUrl returning null in the saveProfile method?

Tags: kotlin

The following code shows the firebase storage upload task which I am using to get the variable downloadUrl, downloadUrl isn't null as it prints in the log but when I call the function saveProfile it returns null, why?

```
var downloadUrl: String? = null

fun upload(bytes: ByteArray) {

    val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference
        .child(
            "images/users/${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid}/profile_image"
        )

    val metadata = StorageMetadata.Builder()
        .setContentType("image/jpg")
        .setContentLanguage("en")
        .build()

    storageReference.putBytes(bytes, metadata).addOnSuccessListener {

        model.listener!!.progressBarGone()
        model.listener!!.toast("Uploaded Successfully")

        val urlTask = it.storage.downloadUrl
        while (!urlTask.isSuccessful);
        this.downloadUrl = urlTask.result.toString()

        Log.d("Upload", "DownloadUrl $downloadUrl")
```

And this is the saveProfile function.

```
fun saveProfile() {

    val user = User()

    if (model.name.isNullOrEmpty() || model.phone.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        model.listener!!.toast("Fields cannot be empty")
        return
    }
    if (downloadUrl.isNullorEmpty()) {

       log.d(TAG, "URL empty")

    }

    user.name = model.name
    user.phone = model.phone
    user.profile_image = downloadUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
this.downloadUrl = urlTask.result.toString()
```

You assign `downloadUrl` to the object that is bound to the lambda you pass to `addOnSuccessListener`, not the global `downloadUrl`. For quick fix, I'd suggest you renaming global `downloadUrl` to some other name that wouldn't be shadowed.

Comment: Still passing null

Comment: ``var url: String? = null `` then ``url = urlTask.result.toString()``

Comment: Are you actually using `url` in `saveProfile`?

Comment: yes, I am saving it the user object, the name and phone get saved.

Comment: If you are calling `saveProfile` before callback from `storageReference.putBytes(bytes, metadata).addOnSuccessListener` fires, `url` won't be set. How are you calling `saveProfile`?

Comment: Well, I wasn't calling it before but thanks for the input I finally worked it out. I declared a null string in ViewModel then used the instance of ViewModel to give it the download URL value then again I used instance of ViewModel to save it to db.